Python multiprocessing pool does not start multiple processes
I am trying to use multiprocessing pool to create multiple processes.
I have a worker function dummy_proc defined as below:
import re 
from multiprocessing import Pool

def regex_check(input_string):
    # Pattern to match both "pm_lat" and "pm_lon_coslat" followed by two floats
    pattern = r"(check1|check2)_(-?\d+\.\d+)_(-?\d+\.\d+)"
    
    # Find all matches of the pattern in the input string
    matches = re.findall(pattern, input_string)
    
    # 'matches' is a list of tuples, each containing the keyword and the two matched float values
    matches = ["_".join(match) for match in matches]
    return matches

def dummy_proc(
    group1: str,
    group2: str,
) -> bool:
    """performs a simple regex check.

    Args:
        group1 (string): The first group of ROIs.
        group2 (string): The second group of ROIs.

    Returns:
        bool: True if no two item in the two lists combined are the same.
    """
    group1_srs = regex_check(group1)
    group2_srs = regex_check(group2)
    return len(set(group1_srs).intersection(set(group2_srs))) == 0

def do_stuff(pairs):
    with Pool(processes=12) as pool:
        result = pool.starmap(dummy_proc, [(pair[0], pair[1]) for pair in pairs])
    return result

which is saved as src.py
Then do_stuff gets imported into a script and executed as below:
from src import do_stuff

def main():
    pairs = [('check1_0.1_0.2', 'check2_0.3_0.4'), ('check2_0.7_0.8', 'check2_0.7_0.8')]
    results = do_stuff(pairs)
    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


When using multiprocessing.Pool as above and then checking on htop to monitor cpu usage, I only see one process being created.
pairs is about 6 million entires long. I have tried setting the chunksize to len(pairs)/processes to no avail.
Am I missing something here? Shouldn't I expect to see 12 processes being listed when using htop?
PS: This is a MWE. This is being run on a HPC that runs Rocky Linux release 8.9 (Green Obsidian)

WHat do you get if you pass the chunksize argument to starmap?  Like in pool.starmap(dummy_proc, [(pair[0], pair[1]) for pair in pairs], chunksize=10_000)  ?
Each task there should be so quick to finish that the first results should be before the last processes in a pool of 12 ever get started - still, there should be more than 1.

I have tried with chunksize set to something like int(len(pairs)/processes), it still just spins one process. Really confused, I should see at least > 1, as you say.

HOW are you running this? you give us two snippets - are they on the same file? What is the O.S.? Can you link to a sample of the data?

This is currently being ran on a HPC that runs rocky linux. I have updated the post to reflect the code structure and what the data actually looks like. The pairs list is essentially a list of tuples that consist of strings like [('check1_0.1_0.2','check2_0.2_0.3',...]; about 6.5 million of them.

Please ensure your [mcve] is actually correct and complete. It currently has at least 2 errors that will prevent it running.

I've tackled a question here where multiprocessing would behave in a weird way because the subprocesses (or pool) were not being instantiated in the main module, but in a an imported one like here. But that case was on MacOS (Which defaults to spawn instead of fork to starting subprocesses), and had one extra incorrectness. The fix was to force fork.

Okay I found an even weirder thing, following the first multiprocessing context manager I have another for a different (performs more CPU operations) function and respective arguments, and that seems to spin up processes just fine. Regardless of what it does, shouldn't the (12) processes for both calls show up when I look at htop output? Let me know if the second function needs to be shared. I find it weird enough that one works and the other does not.
